# Is there a way to tell whether a "long face" is sad or just long?

Tags: meaning, phrases

Obviously, it is impossible to cover all cases, but how do you usually decide whether the "long face" reflects negative emotion or just has the physical property of being long? Answers from gut feelings to linguistic analyses welcome!

Comment: I would say, if someone is making a long face, he is sad. If he is having a long face, he is born with it.

Comment: and when "his long face was looking into the distance"?

Comment: That would need a lot more context to answer. And then it would still be only my opinion.

Comment: Context is everything. Your example appears to describe an emotional situation, but more context could change that, too.

Comment: Simple: measure it. If long, then long. If not long, then sad. (However, if long, then also possibly sad.) ;-)

Comment: A horse walks into a bar, and the bartender asks, "Why the long face?"

Comment: I'd say "long face" falls into the same category as "hot dog". It's such a well-recognized expression, the literal translation almost never applies. Instead, you'd say "a long, narrow face" to avoid confusion.

Comment: What @barrycarter said. I doubt I would ever say “long face” to refer to someone with dolichocephalic facial features. I might say “long, narrow face”, “narrow face”, or just be a bit more technical and say “dolichocephalic face”—but not just “long face” on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether *long face* is idiomatic or literally physically descriptive can be determined by the context. The idiomatic expression is far more common. Commentary on someone's literal long face would be quite personal and possibly discourteous.

Idiomatic use: Why all the *long faces* in here? Did Grandma just die?

Physically descriptive: Alice looked in the fashion magazines for a new hairdo to flatter her *long face*.

Your example, "His long face was looking into the distance" could be either use, depending on the context:

*His long face was looking into the distance, dreading the arrival of the damaged ship.* (Implies sadness, idiomatic.)

*His long face was looking into the distance, emphasizing his receding hairline.* (Comment on personal appearance, *physical* or *literal* use.)